# Search for Android Keystore

Tags: android, keystore, signature, android-keystore

I am picking up an Android application after a year away from the codebase.  I attempted to export a signed application package but cannot for the life of me remember where the original keystore was.  I also don't know the name of the keystore file (and it appears that keystores don't have a file extension either).

What are my options for retrieving the keystore so I can submit an update to the Play store?

Comment: Keystore files normally have a .keystore extension.

Comment: @adelphus No they don't!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @iturki I'm using OSX

Comment: Did you try searching for files with no extension in the system?

Comment: I'm not osx user, but I suggest you go to the [Apple StackExchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) site and ask for `a way to find Type-less files`.

Comment: @iturki : ALL of my release keystores have a .keystore extension and that's with eclipse running on Windows XP and Linux - I'm not sure why you think they don't have a .keystore extension.

Comment: @Squonk All mine have no extension, and that is with Eclipse and AS on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time.

**There no way to submit an update without having the same keystore files**, 
unless you find the keystore that was used to the submitted app.

Keystore files does not have an extension. What I do is to a .keystore extension when saving them.
e.g. someName.keystore

This way I can search them and find them easier.